# localhost server in android

Tags: android, sockets

I have created the local host server in android and i am trying to communicate with my ajax call.I successfully connected to the server but unable to receive response.xmlhttp status returns 0 only.if i created the server as the sepa

**Ajax call**

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         document.getElementById("myDiv3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.readyState+"";
        // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
          document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.status+"";        
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    //  document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML="2";
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8888/Server",true);
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**server code**

```
try{
          String fromclient;
          String toclient;

          ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (8888);

          System.out.println ("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 8888");

          while(true) 
          {
            Socket connected = Server.accept();
             System.out.println( " THE CLIENT"+" "+
             connected.getInetAddress() +":"+connected.getPort()+" IS CONNECTED ");



             PrintWriter outToClient =
                new PrintWriter(
                   connected.getOutputStream(),true);
             outToClient.write("<html><head>hai</head></html>");
             connected.close();

          }
        }
          catch(Exception e)
          {

          }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The term "localhost" is not correct at all here. "Development machine" or "host machine" would me more accurate.

Anyway, change:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8888/Server",true);
```

and use:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://10.0.2.2:8888/Server",true);
```

Remember to check your firewall/iptables and all that stuff. I didn't check your code for any other error but this should do the trick regarding the connection.